# How to remove a prefix in BQ column

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I need to remove a prefix 0 from the data in specific column in BQ. How it should be done? Using substr function?

Example:

| id |
| --- |
| 012345 |
| 0012345 |
| 00012345 |

and the output should be without zeros, so should be like:

| id |
| --- |
| 12345 |
| 12345 |
| 12345 |

in all listed cases above.

I know how to add a prefix:

```
UPDATE
  table.name
SET
 id = CAST(CONCAT('99999', CAST(id AS STRING)) AS INTEGER)
WHERE
  code = 'US' and cast(id as string)
```

Comment: Can you share input and output?

Comment: Do you want to keep it as string or integer?

Comment: The output should be a string format

Answer (score 1):

Using **LTRIM**,

```sql
SELECT LTRIM(id, '0') id 
  FROM UNNEST(['012345', '0012345', '00012345']) id
```

Output will be:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you cast your string to integer, you'll remove the zeroes. Then in order to get back your string, it's sufficient to cast back to string.

```
UPDATE table.name
SET id = CAST(CAST(id AS INTEGER) AS STRING)
WHERE code = 'US'
```

Does it work for you?

Answer (score 0):

The below query should work

```
SELECT REPLACE(LTRIM(REPLACE('00012345', '0', ' ')),' ', '0');
SELECT REPLACE(LTRIM(REPLACE('0012345', '0', ' ')),' ', '0');
```

Answer (score 0):

I've used regex:

```
set id, REGEXP_REPLACE(id, r"^[0]+(.*)", "\\1")
from  table.name 
where id like '0%'
```